# Hide all divs with same class but the one clicked and change text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 questions in this one question.

The first one is:
I know that we could do that by applying `.not(this)` on the object but I don't know why is that happening. I have applied the above mentioned technique but I am not able to get it working properly.

Here is FOF my HTML:

```
<div class="row-fluid offer">
    <div class="span2">
        <img class="profile_picture" src="admin/profile_pictures/default_profile_picture.png">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="username">
                <p style="font-weight: bold;">Mohammad Danish Siddiqui</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="content">
                <p class="content">zaza</p><span class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -30px; margin-right: 20px;"><button class="accept_offer btn btn-success" data-offer-id="32">Accept Offer</button></span>
                <textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">zaza</textarea>
                <button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick="editPostOffer(&quot;18&quot;,&quot;32&quot;,&quot;[object HTMLTextAreaElement]&quot;);">Save Edits</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="date">
                <p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>2013-12-19</p>
            </div><a href="conversation.php?id=17">Contact this person</a>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row-fluid offer">
    <div class="span2">
        <img class="profile_picture" src="admin/profile_pictures/default_profile_picture.png">
    </div>
    <div class="span10">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="username">
                <p style="font-weight: bold;">Mohammad Danish Siddiqui</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="content">
                <p class="content">zaza</p><span class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -30px; margin-right: 20px;"><button class="accept_offer btn btn-success" data-offer-id="32">Accept Offer</button></span>
                <textarea class="hide span12" id="edited_content">zaza</textarea>
                <button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small" id="save_edits" onclick="editPostOffer(&quot;18&quot;,&quot;32&quot;,&quot;[object HTMLTextAreaElement]&quot;);">Save Edits</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="hide btn btn-primary btn-small cancel_edits">Cancel Edits</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="date">
                <p class="pull-right"><strong><span class="muted">Offered on: </span></strong>2013-12-19</p>
            </div><a href="conversation.php?id=17">Contact this person</a>&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is SOF my Javascript that should be responsible for this abnormal behaviour:

```
$(".accept_offer").on('click', function () {
    var offer_id = $(this).data("offer-id");
    if ($(this).text() == "Accept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {
            id: offer_id,
            acceptance: "accepted"
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("hide");
                }, 2500);
                $(".accept_offer").not(this).each(function () {
                    $(this).addClass("hide");
                });
                $(this).text("Unaccept Offer").refresh();
                $("#has_accepted_offer_alert").removeClass("hide");
            }
        }, 'json');
    } else if ($(this).text() == "Unaccept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {
            id: offer_id,
            acceptance: "unaccepted"
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                $("#unacceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#unacceptedOfferModal").modal("hide");
                }, 2500);
                $(".accept_offer").not(this).each(function () {
                    $(this).removeClass("hide");
                });
                $(this).text("Accept Offer").refresh();
                $("#has_accepted_offer_alert").removeClass("hide");

            }
        }, 'json');
    }
});
```

I don't know why but this code:

```
$(".accept_offer").not(this).each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hide");
});
```

Or this code:

```
$(".accept_offer").not(this).each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("hide");
});
```

Is not working properly. It should hide or show the rest of the divs except for this but it's not doing it. Nothing is happening when I click it except for the modal being shown and hid.

The second question is:
I am trying to change the button which is clicked but it's also not changing. The code is the same that is mentioned above. This just means that when the specific button with the `.accept_offer` class is clicked I want to change the button text according to the if conditions.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you elaborate your second question

Comment: @dreamweiver I have edited my question and added a little description. Now please help. :)

Comment: @mohammmed Areeb Siddiqui: try addding the `context: this` within `$.Post{...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is not the element in that scope, it's the XHR object in the ajax function as it's inside the callback of the `$.post` function, and that creates a new scope

```
$(".accept_offer").on('click', function () {
    var offer_id = $(this).data("offer-id");

    var self = this; // store the value of this

    if ($(this).text() == "Accept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {
            id: offer_id,
            acceptance: "accepted"
        }, function (data) { // this creates a new scope, and changes "this"

            // now use self inside this scope

            $(".accept_offer").not(self).addClass("hide");

        }, 'json');
    } ....
```

do the same for the other condition as well

Comment: this again hides both of them :/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - Did you change it the way I told you to, like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/H8bVT/

Comment: +1 for the answer of first question. I would accept the answer for the answer of second question.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui - How would I know what the button looks like. Is this a jQuery UI button or something ?

Comment: No, @adeneo, it's a bootstrap button with `btn`,`btn-success` as it's classes.

Comment: And you used `self` there to, exactly like in the fiddle, as `this` is still not the element

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.each()` in your context, since you want to hide all the elements with that class. And [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) can accept Jquery object as a parameter.

Try,

```
$(".accept_offer").not($(this)).addClass('hide');
```

Comment: Now it's hiding both of them. :/

Comment: But it's hiding both the buttons at once, it's not taking caring of the one that has been clicked. :/

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui Now try, I just written remove instead of add.

Answer (score 0):

You are using not(this) to same selector that means firstly selector and assigning .not(this) to same selector will remove the selector. So use like this:

```
$(".accept_offer").each(function () {  
   $(".accept_offer").removeClass("hide");
   $(this).addClass("hide");
});
```

Or try like this:

```
$(".accept_offer").each(function () {  
   $(".accept_offer").not(self).removeClass("hide");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hey you can try this way

```
$(".accept_offer").on('click',function () {
     $(this).addClass('activeClass');
});

$('div:not(.activeClass)').hide();
```

Comment: this is kinda complicated PLUS this one is adding a lot of code into the script which I donot like btw I would consider this answer if I didn't get a more simpler and accurate version of my question.

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui:I have optimized it now, try if works for you

Comment: Thanks but now I have adapted the way that *@adeneo* told please consider answering my second question. :)

Answer (score 0):

this does not refers to the Button having class `"accept_offer".you need to catch the selector at click of the button .like

```
$(".accept_offer").on('click', function () {
   var element=this; //Save the clicked Button
   var offer_id = $(this).data("offer-id");
    if ($(this).text() == "Accept Offer") {
        $.post("admin/post_offer/set_post_offer_acceptance.php", {
            id: offer_id,
            acceptance: "accepted"
        }, function (data) {
            if (data.status == "success") {
                $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("show");
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $("#acceptedOfferModal").modal("hide");
                }, 2500);
                $(".accept_offer").not(element).each(function () { 
//Do each operation insted of "element" which is saved
                        $(this).addClass("hide");
                    });
                    $(elemnt).text("Unaccept Offer").refresh();
                    $("#has_accepted_offer_alert").removeClass("hide");
                }
            }, 'json');

    });
```

Comment: that's what *@adeneo* told.

Comment: Try answering my second question please :)

Comment: Again instead of this try using $(element).text("Unaccept Offer").refresh() to change the button